# Async multiple http request (ajax) in laravel framework

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, apache, nginx

i try to hit multiple API with AJAX call in Laravel framework.
When i see the network process in the browser. I see the second Ajax call is only executed after the first Ajax call finish (return response) (sequential).

**First attempt :**

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/getVA",
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            cache: true,
            beforeSend: function() {

            },
            success: function(response) {
    }});
    
$.ajax({
            url: "/getVA",
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            cache: true,
            beforeSend: function() {

            },
            success: function(response) {
    }});
```

RESULT : Second /getVA is run after first getVA

**Second attempt :**

```
 async function makeAsyncApiCall(url, method, data) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });

  return await response.json();
}

const apiRequests = [
  { url: '/getVA', method: 'GET' },
  { url: '/getVA', method: 'GET' },
  { url: '/getVA', method: 'GET' },
  { url: '/getVA', method: 'GET' },
  { url: '/getVA', method: 'GET' }
];

const promises = apiRequests.map(({ url, method, data }) => makeAsyncApiCall(url, method, data));

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(responses => {
    responses.forEach(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

RESULT :
still looks sequential to me
[image]

**Third Attempt**

I hit the rest api on the first tab (Dashboard), when i try to open new tab and open the other page of my web page (PrivacyPolicy). The privacy policy tab waits for dashboard tab finish api load, then privacy policy tab load successfully

**Target**

Currently i have a task to upload file to an api. Then, there's an api to check the progress and will update the progress concurrently. But in my case, check progress api pending(based on browser network) until the first upload return response.

Is there any setting that should be done in Laravel. Or is it server setting like Nginx or apache ?

Comment: Wow this is weird (I have a 2s sleep on my URL), I can reproduce it in Chrome the following way: hard refresh means async (all requests run instantly; they return roughly after 2s). Soft refresh means in series (returns after 2s/4s/6s/8s/...)

Comment: It's not a caching issue since I am returning a timestamp from the URL and it returns a fresh timestamp every request. Weird stuff.

Comment: it seems like you run php artisan serve which handles requests one by one. If you are using php-fpm, maybe you set children count to 1, or somehow limit the throughput

Comment: by the way, your second attempt should work fine

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be some Chrome caching quirk/issue. What currently seems to work (Chrome 113.0.5672.127) is adding the following header to the server response:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3, must-revalidate
```

Where `max-age` is the number of seconds for how long the request is valid. I am getting mixed results with `max-age=0` or `max-age=1` and I have no clue why it works this oddly. You will encounter this weird caching behaviour even when just navigating across pages.